# How can I display the content of a map on the console?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, stdmap

I have a `map` declared as follows:

```
map < string , list < string > > mapex ; list< string > li;
```

How can I display the items stored in the above map on the console?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well it depends on how you want to display them, but you can always iterate them easily:

```
typedef map<string, list<string>>::const_iterator MapIterator;
for (MapIterator iter = mapex.begin(); iter != mapex.end(); iter++)
{
    cout << "Key: " << iter->first << endl << "Values:" << endl;
    typedef list<string>::const_iterator ListIterator;
    for (ListIterator list_iter = iter->second.begin(); list_iter != iter->second.end(); list_iter++)
        cout << " " << *list_iter << endl;
}
```

Comment: @triclosan: You can pre-increment too, doesn't matter in this case. Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: using of post-increment gains to extra temporary object creation

Comment: @triclosan: Perhaps, or the compiler optimises it away for you. Impossible to say without trying it. And in the grand scheme of things we are using standard iostream console output which performance-wise dwarfs any cost of an extra object iterator object.

Answer (score 39):

Update (Back to the future): with C++11 range-based for loops –

```
std::map<Key, Value> m { ... /* initialize it */ ... };

for (const auto &p : m) {
    std::cout << "m[" << p.first << "] = " << p.second << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I'd try the following

```
void dump_list(const std::list<string>& l) {
  for ( std::list<string>::const_iterator it = l.begin(); l != l.end(); l++ ) {
    cout << *l << endl;
  }
}

void dump_map(const std::map<string, std::list<string>>& map) {
  for ( std::map<string,std::list<string>>::const_iterator it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); it++) {
    cout << "Key: " << it->first << endl;
    cout << "Values" << endl;
    dump_list(it->second);
}
```

Comment: Got `expected unqualified-id before '<' token` at the first line: `void dump_list(const std::list<string>& l) {`. Do I have to include something?

Comment: In dump_list it should be like :

std::vector<type>::const_iterator it = l.begin();
    for ( it; it != l.end(); ++it ) {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }

and not l in the cout! Otherwise it was very helpful to me 

/Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I'm a little off topic here...

I guess you want to dump the map content for debugging. I like to mention that the next gdb release (version 7.0) will have a built in python interpreter which will be used by the gcc libstdc++ to provide stl pretty printers.  Here is an example for your case

```
  #include <map>
  #include <map>
  #include <list>
  #include <string>

  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
    typedef map<string, list<string> > map_type;
    map_type mymap;

    list<string> mylist;
    mylist.push_back("item 1");
    mylist.push_back("item 2");
    mymap["foo"] =  mylist;
    mymap["bar"] =  mylist;

    return 0; // stopped here
  }
```

which results in

```
(gdb) print mymap
$1 = std::map with 2 elements = {
  ["bar"] = std::list = {
    [0] = "item 1",
    [1] = "item 2"
  },
  ["foo"] = std::list = {
    [0] = "item 1",
    [1] = "item 2"
  }
}
```

Yay!

Answer (score 2):

Another form, using `<algorithm>`:

```
void printPair(const pair<string, list<string> > &p)
{
    cout << "Key: " << p.first << endl;
    copy(p.second.begin(), p.second.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
}    
for_each(mapex.begin(), mapex.end(), printPair);
```

Test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void printPair(const pair<string, list<string> > &p)
{
    cout << "Key: " << p.first << endl;
    copy(p.second.begin(), p.second.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
}

int main()
{
    map<string, list<string> >  mapex;

    list<string> mylist1;
    mylist1.push_back("item 1");
    mylist1.push_back("item 2");
    mapex["foo"] =  mylist1;
    list<string> mylist2;
    mylist2.push_back("item 3");
    mylist2.push_back("item 4");
    mylist2.push_back("item 5");
    mapex["bar"] =  mylist2;

    for_each(mapex.begin(), mapex.end(), printPair);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a quite generic overloaded function, which is good for two purposes:

1. It works with any `map`.
2. It allows for using `<<`.

The function is

```
template<class key_t, class value_t>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const map<key_t, value_t>& m) {
    for (typename map<key_t, value_t>::const_iterator it = m.begin();
            it != m.end(); it++) {
        os << "Key: " << it->first << ", Value: " << it->second;
    }
    return os;
}
```

`cout <<` will work with any `map` for which `<<` is defined for `typename`s `key_t` and `value_t`. In your case, this is not defined for `value_t` (= `list<string>`), so you also have to define it.
In a similar spirit, you can use

```
template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const list<T>& l) {
    for (typename list<T>::const_iterator it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); it++) {
        os << "\"" << *it << "\", ";
    }
    return os;
}
```

So, you may:

1. Add these two functions.
2. Add the prototypes where needed.
3. Use `using namespace std;` (or add `std::` as needed).
4. Use, e.g.,

    `cout << mapex << endl;`

    `cout << li << endl;`

Remember that if there is any other viable candidate for the `<<`s just defined (which I take there is not, otherwise you would likely not ask this question), it may take precedence over the present ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) features, then I think [range-based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) as proposed in [The Paramagnetic Croissant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27278347/2675154) provide the most readable option. However, if [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) is available to you, then you can combine those loops with  [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) to further increase readability, because you no longer need to use the `first` and `second` members. For your specific use case, my solution would look as follows:

```
std::map<std::string, std::list<std::string>> mapex;
mapex["a"] = { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
mapex["b"] = { "5", "6", "7" };

for (const auto &[k, v] : mapex) {
    std::cout << "m[" << k.c_str() << "] =";
    for (const auto &s : v)
        std::cout << " " << s.c_str();
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> m[a] = 1 2 3 4
>   m[b] = 5 6 7

[Code on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e97e33b5dfc8bf35)