# How can I print out C++ map values?

Tags: c++, dictionary, for-loop, printing, std-pair

I have a `map` like this:

```
map<string, pair<string, string>> myMap;
```

And I've inserted some data into my map using:

```
myMap.insert(make_pair(first_name, make_pair(middle_name, last_name)));
```

How can I now print out all the data in my map?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4850473/485561).

Comment: You loop through the map using an iterator, take the key, the members of the pair, and apply `cout::operator<<` to them. It's not that hard, really.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063453/how-to-display-map-contents

This question and answer should do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to loop through a c++ map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844886/how-to-loop-through-a-c-map)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

```
for(map<string, pair<string,string> >::const_iterator it = myMap.begin();
    it != myMap.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second.first << " " << it->second.second << "\n";
}
```

In C++11, you don't need to spell out `map<string, pair<string,string> >::const_iterator`. You can use `auto`

```
for(auto it = myMap.cbegin(); it != myMap.cend(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second.first << " " << it->second.second << "\n";
}
```

Note the use of `cbegin()` and `cend()` functions.

Easier still, you can use the range-based for loop:

```
for(const auto& elem : myMap)
{
   std::cout << elem.first << " " << elem.second.first << " " << elem.second.second << "\n";
}
```

Comment: isn't the last one slower?

Comment: @Paul: I edited it to to `const auto&` to avoid the copying of the elements. Hope that is what you meant. Other than this, no, the last one is not slower

Answer (score 34):

Since [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) you can use [range-based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) together with [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) for iterating over your map. This improves readability, as you reduce the amount of needed `first` and `second` members in your code:

```
std::map<std::string, std::pair<std::string, std::string>> myMap;
myMap["x"] = { "a", "b" };
myMap["y"] = { "c", "d" };

for (const auto &[k, v] : myMap)
    std::cout << "m[" << k << "] = (" << v.first << ", " << v.second << ") " << std::endl;
```

Output:

> m[x] = (a, b)
>   m[y] = (c, d)

[Code on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8e9c61e4995488e)

Comment: Good update! You might want to take your parameters as const reference in the for loop.

Comment: When I try doing the for loop, I get "identifier "k" is undefined."

Comment: @AlphaFoxtrot: Did you really compile it for C++17? As you can see from the link to Coliru, the code is actually working.

Comment: Ah I see. I recently downloaded Visual Studio and I thought it would put me on the latest. Turns out I was using C++98.

Answer (score 31):

If your compiler supports (at least part of) C++11 you could do something like:

```
for (auto& t : myMap)
    std::cout << t.first << " " 
              << t.second.first << " " 
              << t.second.second << "\n";
```

For C++03 I'd use `std::copy` with an insertion operator instead:

```
typedef std::pair<string, std::pair<string, string> > T;

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, T const &t) { 
    return os << t.first << " " << t.second.first << " " << t.second.second;
}

// ...
std:copy(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: Why is the & required in the above snipped?




`for (auto& t : myMap)
    std::cout << t.first << " " 
              << t.second.first << " " 
              << t.second.second << "\n";`

Comment: Using a reference `&` avoids making a copy during the loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to declare an iterator first  as
`map<string ,string> :: iterator it;`

and after that print it out by looping over the map using iterator from `myMap.begin()` to `myMap.end()` and print out key and value pairs in the map with `it->first` for key and `it->second` for value.

```
  map<string ,string> :: iterator it;
    for(it=myMap.begin();it !=myMap.end();++it)
      {
       std::cout << it->first << ' ' <<it->second;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try ***range based loop*** like this:

```
for(auto& x:myMap){
        cout<<x.first<<" "<<x.second.first<<" "<<x.second.second<<endl;
}
```