# Display contents of a STL container on a window? window.h

Tags: c++, windows, stl

So basically what I want to do is display the contents of a map on a child window of a parent window.
Both the parts of map the key and value side by side.
Should I iterate through the map save the values separately in char arrays and then pass it to the function?

```
CreateWindow("STATIC",MyMap,
          WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,150,80,300,200,hwnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Is there any way to do that? When I have to display an array I just simply write the name of the array and it gets displayed.. and also for strings.. 
What can I do for the map?

Comment: Use a `LISTVIEW` control in report mode with 2 columns. Iterate the `map` adding items to the ListView. Or use the ListView in virtual mode, using `LVN_GETDISPINFO` notifications to retrieve values from the `map` for display.

Answer (score 0):

[CreateWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function requires a "LPCTSTR" string for its title argument.
First generate a string from the map, and use that string for the window name.

See [Stackoverflow question how to get string values from the map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070940/c-printing-out-map-values).

Comment: Note that `"STATIC"` is a MS Windows common control (a static text label), for which the "title" proeprty really is the content.