# Inserting values into map with pair - error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++98

I'm a little new to maps (and c programming in general) and am trying to insert some values into a map that takes a `string` as a key, and a paired `<double,double>` as the corresponding values.

When I try and compile the code, I am presented with the error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
  values.insert(make_pair(string, pair<double,double>("test", 0.123456,0.98765 ) ) );
                                      ^
```

```c++
std::map<std::string, std::pair<double, double> > values;
values.insert(make_pair(string, pair<double,double>("test", 0.123456,0.98765 ) ) );
```

Do I need to utilise the iterator type in order to do this? Otherwise I have a feeling it's how I have structured this: `"test", 0.123456,0.98765`.

Comment: That's not C. Please change the tags, or use the correct compiler.

Comment: Start by making a map of `string --> double` and once you have figured out how to do it properly, figure how to create a pair alone and finally figure out how to use them together. One can easily notice that you use ( instead of < after `make_pair`. Also, you try to pass 3 parameters in the innermost parenthesis while both `make_pair` and `pair` constructor have 2 parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```c++
values.insert(make_pair("test",make_pair(0.12312312, 0.56756756)));

    cout << values.size() << endl;

    for(map<string, pair<double,double> >::const_iterator it = radar_values.begin(); it != values.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << it->first << endl;
        cout << it->second.first << endl;
        cout << it->second.second << endl;
    }
```

Reference: [How can I print out C++ map values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070940/how-can-i-print-out-c-map-values/55278718)