# How to print map content with the data type is a class object

Tags: c++, dictionary

I referred to this link about print map content:

[print map content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063453/how-to-display-map-contents)

So i know the basic of printing map content,however I am not sure if I defined my map in the following way with data type is a class object and with other codes as shown below:

```
typedef map <string, fsdbSig *> Pinname_sig;
Pinname_sig _Pinname_sig; 
Pinname_sig :: iterator itPS;
```

I would like to know the way to print the map content is the same as the link above?

```
for (itPS = _Pinname_sig.begin(); itPS != _Pinname_sig.end(); ++itPS){
    cout << "Jden-key:" << itPS->first << "," << "value:" << itPS->second <<endl;
}
```

If yes then when to use the overload operator<< as I saw some posts using the method.

Hi @computer

```
  struct fsdbSig
{
    public:
        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& , const fsdbSig&); //jaden
        char * _name;       // signal name
        fsdbVarType _type;  // signal type
        ushort_T _lbitnum;  // signal left bit number
        ushort_T _rbitnum;  // signal right bit number
        fsdbBytesPerBit _bpb;   // signal byte per bit
        byte_T _value;      // signal value

        fsdbSig(char * name, fsdbVarType type, ushort_T lbitnum, ushort_T rbitnum, fsdbBytesPerBit bpb, byte_T value ) // constructor
        {
            _name = name;
            _type = type;
            _lbitnum = lbitnum ;
            _rbitnum = rbitnum ;
            _bpb = bpb;
            _value = value ;
        }   

};
```

But happen error undefined reference to `operator<<(std::basic_ostream

Comment: I'm confused as to whether this question is about how to send a pointer-to-object to a `std::ostream` or how to write an insertion operator for your mapped element type. Can you clarify the question (or maybe its *both* or *neither* of those?).

Comment: @WhozCraig Hi.Actually is both question I hope to know the answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically to print this you will do:

```
typedef map <string, fsdbSig *> Pinname_sig;
Pinname_sig _Pinname_sig; 
Pinname_sig::iterator itPS;

for (itPS = _Pinname_sig.begin(); itPS != _Pinname_sig.end(); ++itPS){
    cout << "Jden-key:"<< itPS->first<< ","<< "value:"<< *(itPS->second) <<endl;
                                                         ^ since itPS->second
                                                         is pointer to fsdbSig
}
```

however this will work only if `fsdbSig` is a type with defined `operator<<`, something like this in global namespace:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const fsdbSig&);
```

or this in `fsdbSig` class:

```
class fsdbSig {
          public:
             friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& , const fsdbSig&);
     };
```

if this operator needs access to private data of `fsdbSig` object. And notice: if your class fsdbSig is complex you need to know what it means to print it.

after your edit:

> Hi,after i copied to the class now got this error: undefined reference
>   to `operator<<(std::basic_ostream >&,
>   fsdbSig const&)'

Sorry, I thought you will know that you have to add also definition of your `operator<<` not only declaration, it seems you are really beginner. You have undefined reference because function is called which isn't defined. This is link error. So what to do now? Provide definition of `operator<<`. However this can have many meanings what it is to print object of your class:

- maybe it means print its name
- or maybe it means print its name and do "Bi bip!"
- or maybe print name and value

This is why I said you need to know what it is, for example you might define it as

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const fsdbSig& f){
    os<<"My name is: "<<f.name;
    return os;
}
```

and it don't have to be friend of a structure since all in a C++ structure is public, everyone has access to it. So this **definition** can be put outside structure and you should remove then its **declaration** from inside structure.

---

additional note:
My advice is to always use the google search engine first, before asking here. You will always find quickly answer to such basic question as

> error: undefined reference

and always choose links to stack overflow posts first if there are listed any of them.

Comment: I tried to use *(itPS->second) and happened with this error
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::operator

Comment: did you define operator<< for class fsdbSig?  plaese see my answer, you need to define this operator. please insert also code of class fsdbSig if you don't know how to define this operator

Comment: @milk4508 and notice: if your class fsdbSig is complex you need to know what it means to print it

Comment: I will try now and feedback to you.DO you mean I just need to copy
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& , const fsdbSig&); to class fsdbsig ?

Comment: Hi,after i copied to the class now got this error:
undefined reference to `operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, fsdbSig const&)'

Comment: I have editted my post with the answer you gave me as shown above

Comment: Hi @computer ,ya i am still a beginner :(.
Actually I am always blur at the overload operator part.I totally dont understand when and why we need to make use of that.But I will keep learning to understand it.And really thank you put your time to explain to me.I can alway refer back to here when i need to know about overload operator brief idea.Btw i tried to make my code become " cout << "Jden-key:"<< itPS->first<< ","<< "value:"<< itPS->second->_name <<endl; ".It wont come out any error.In this case will it work ?

Comment: yes this will work because itPS->second->_name is char* right? and there is std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& , const char*); defined right? I am sure you have use it many times like cout<<_name, however cout<<fsdbSig is not defined, you have to provide this definition by yourself.

Comment: I am not sure whether there is any std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& , const char*); defined because i am reading people codes which link to alot of files and complex classes(OOP).But i did see code like this friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, list<string>& lst);friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, map<string,double>& mp); in other class from other file but not the struct fsdbsig.Or maybe it works coz of inherit from the class which defined that?

Comment: no, version cout<<itPS->second->_name <<endl; works because itPS->second->_name ic of type char*

Comment: So you mean there is for sure have the friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& , const fsdbSig&); defined somewhr in the whole code files i read?

Comment: no. cout<<itPS->second->_name <<endl; works without any additional defs because itPS->second->_name ic of type char* and std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& , const char*); is defined "somewhere". cout<<fsdbSig will not work unless you defined std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& , const fsdbSig&);

Comment: Hi Computer,Finally I understand it.Thanks very much. :)